# Upload the image with $http.post() inside angular.forEach function

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, post

I am trying to upload image into the folder with `angularjs`and `php`.

Here is html part:

```
<button ng-click="addNewEvent()">Add Event</button>
<form ng-submit="addRoadmapEvent(events)">
  <span ng-repeat="event in events">
    <input type="text" ng-model="event.month" required=""/>
    <input type="file" ng-model="event.img" file-input="files" />
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Function `addNewEvent()` allows to add another row with month and image so I will have something like this:

[image]

Then after pressing submit button I want to move selected images into my folder, I am using directive for it and then `addRoadmapEvent` function:

```
$scope.addRoadmapEvent = function (events){
  var imgs = [];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  //set the data array
  angular.forEach(events, function(event){
    imgs.push(event.img);
  });

  var i = 0;
  angular.forEach(imgs, function(file){
    console.log(i++);
    form_data.append('file', file[0]);
    $http.post('House/house_action.php/roadmap_img', form_data, {transformRequest: angular.identity,headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}}).then(function(response){  
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }); 
};
```

It works perfectly the only problem is `$http.post`. Its posting same photo twice:

[image]

How can i make it send one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `FormData` constructor inside the loop:

```
$scope.addRoadmapEvent = function (events){
  var imgs = [];
  ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶m̶_̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶F̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶(̶)̶;̶
  //set the data array
  angular.forEach(events, function(event){
    imgs.push(event.img);
  });

  var i = 0;
  angular.forEach(imgs, function(file){
    console.log(i++);
    //INSIDE the loop
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file[0]);
    $http.post('House/house_action.php/roadmap_img', form_data, {
         transformRequest: angular.identity,
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'Process-Data': false
         }
    }).then(function(response){  
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }); 
};
```